# Sum by month in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I have question about one function that i require in Google Sheets. I have a schedule of visitors and another sheet that includes every statistic data. I need to make a table which will contain sum of number, but statistic must be by month. In my source sheet i have columns which include date and amount. All that I need it's function. I tried it with SUMIF and SUMIFS but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how can I cope with this trouble? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
=SUM(FILTER(vistorscolumnA:A,monthcolumnB:B="month"))
```

A little hard to get you all the way there without seeing your format, but this should get you close.