# Google Sheets - Sum Elements of a Column's Range by Month

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Before making this post, I have read the following posts:

- [Sum by month in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829902/sum-by-month-in-google-sheet)
- [Getting sum of the amount per month - Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959278/getting-sum-of-the-amount-per-month-google-sheet)
- [Google Sheets Sumifs with date condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381986/google-sheets-sumifs-with-date-condition)

And the following websites' pages:

- [Sum by Month in Google Sheets Using Combined SUMIF Formula](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/sum-by-month-in-google-sheets/)
- [Sum If By Month – Excel & Google Sheets](https://www.automateexcel.com/formulas/sum-if-month/)

What I try to do is just to do a conditional sumation between the elements of a range contained in a column if they meet the condition of being within a month. The setup of my sheet is the following:

- A named range DATES (A4:A1000)
- A named range EXPENSES (C4:C1000)

And I have tried the following functions (A6 is a cell that contains a Date):

- = SUMPRODUCT(EXPENSES, --(MONTH(DATES) = MONTH(A6))) **[This one seems to work only in Excel]**
- = SUMIFS(EXPENSES, DATES, ">="&DATE(YEAR(A6), MONTH(A6), 1), DATES, "<="&EOMONTH(A6,0))
- = ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(EXPENSES, MONTH(DATES), 12, YEAR(DATES), 2020))
- ={{unique(ArrayFormula(text(DATES,"MMMM")))},
  {ArrayFormula(sumif(ArrayFormula(text(DATES,"MMMM")),
  unique(ArrayFormula(text(DATES,"MMMM"))),EXPENSES))}}
- etc.

All attempts return me a "Formula Parse Error" with the code #ERROR ([Meaning Google Sheets cannot make sense of the formula you have written](https://productivityspot.com/formula-parse-error-google-sheets/#ERROR_Message)). I honestly don't know where is my error, whether I pass incorrect parameter types or forget to add braces, commas, etc.

Comment: `SUMIFS()` should work. Can you shoe some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first formula you propose (the one using `SUMPRODUCT`) actually works for me. And actually the double negation is not even necessary. You may have problems if you have empty dates so you may just add a `ISDATE(DATES)` in the condition, like so:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(EXPENSES; ISDATE(DATES)*MONTH(DATES)=MONTH(A6))
```

Also note that a syntax error could be caused by your locale. Note that I'm using a semicolon `;` instead of a comma `,` because in my locale commas are used as the decimal separator. Something similar might be happening to you.

### References

- [SUMPRODUCT function (Google Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294)
- [MONTH function (Google Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052)
- [ISDATE function (Google Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061381)

Comment: You are correct. The key was in the locale's separators (whether semicolon or comma). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try one of the following formulas
*(where `A2:A` is your dates range, `A1` is your date and `C2:C` is your expenses range)*

If all dates are within the same year try

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(MONTH(A2:A),"="&MONTH(A1),C2:C))
```

If you have different years use

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(MONTH(A2:A)&YEAR(A2:A),"="&MONTH(A1)&YEAR(A1),C2:C))
```