# Sum by Month in Google Sheets, How to sum all the values in August

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Could you advise which formula can be used to sum all the values in August ?  Thank you so much.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CZ8HdgaRCYzoyB_H34koMPc5zcLh62hi4MruO4WzpJQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets - Sum Elements of a Column's Range by Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67613261/google-sheets-sum-elements-of-a-columns-range-by-month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=sum(filter(2:2,month(1:1)=8))
```